# There are two games of chess.... (conditional probability).

Tags: probability, game-theory, independence

There are two games of chess, the first round and the second round are played against the same opponent of unknown skill.

> $W_1$ is the event that round one is won by me.
>
> $W_2$ is the event that round two is won by me.
>
> $A$ is the skill of the opponent is known in general.
>
> $A_1$ is the skill of the opponent is known in round one.

Given that I'm assuming the conditional probabilities are independent

> $P(W_2|A)*P(W_1|A)=P(W_2,W_1|A)$
> which means
> $P(W_2|W_1,A)=P(W_2|A)$

Why does the statement $P(W_2|W_1,A)$ seem incomplete? Shouldn't we be conditioning like this?

> $P(W_2|W_1givenA_1,A)$

It's confusing in the sense that $P(W_2|W_1,A)$ seems incomplete due to the fact that I am not conditioning on $W_1$ given "knownledge of the player's skill in the first round" shouldn't that knowledge play a part in the shaping of the event of $W_1$ thus we should include $A_1$. I know that $P(event|A)$ is a function, but i'm more confused about how the knowledge of $A_1$ shapes the event $W_1$.

Perhaps, I'm confused about how events behave in the conditional part of the equation:

> $P(event|"confused part")$ ?

I should mention that the skill of the opponent is invariant throughout the matches.

Comment: I think your $X$'s turned into $W$'s at some point.

Comment: $W_1$ seems to be independent of $A_1$. I understand $A_1$ as known skill of opponent after you play the first game.

Comment: Ah yes, i intended $A_1$ to be the known skill of the player before the 1st game. I should mention that the skill of the player is invariant throughout the matches to exclude things like the player getting emotional and etc. @Masacroso